# Is there any way to stop execution of an Azure Cognitive Search indexer?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've reset an indexer assigned to an SQL data source with millions of rows but forgot to update some values in the data source.
Now I have to wait until the indexer completes the indexation and then I'll have to reset it again. Is it possible to forcibly stop the execution of the indexer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting [disabled : true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer#request-body) on the indexer resource should stop the indexer's current invocation. You can then set disabled back to false once you're ready to run it again.